# OracleDataAdapter.Fill throws "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, ado.net

**`OracleDataAdapter.Fill`** throws an exception: "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended". Usual culprits according to many posts is that some spaces or semicolon at the end. I copied the statement and executed on Oracle "Sql Developer", and it works..

Here is my code (kind of)

```
var stmt = "SELECT fmly.fmly_id, fmly.fmly_key, fmly.fmly_db_view_nm, MI_DBUMS_UTIL.GET_BASELINE_TABLE_NAME(fmly.fmly_id) blTableName " +
                                    "FROM mi_families AS fmly WHERE fmly.fmly_type_cd = 'ENFA' " +
                                    "AND fmly.fmly_id not in (SELECT fmly_id from mi_exclude_families WHERE context_cd = 'REVERT') " +
                                    "AND EXISTS " + "(SELECT 1 FROM mi_entities_bl AS enty_bl WHERE fmly.fmly_id = enty_bl.fmly_id);";    

var conn = new OracleConnection("<connection string>");
var cmd = new OracleCommand(stmt, conn)
IDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

conn.Open();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
adapter.Fill(ds)
```

Can someone plz help me with the reason for the exception thrown?

Comment: Remove the semicolon inside quotes at the end and test the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this?

```
var stmt = "SELECT fmly.fmly_id, fmly.fmly_key, fmly.fmly_db_view_nm, MI_DBUMS_UTIL.GET_BASELINE_TABLE_NAME(fmly.fmly_id) blTableName " +
                                    "FROM mi_families AS fmly WHERE fmly.fmly_type_cd = 'ENFA' " +
                                    "AND fmly.fmly_id not in (SELECT fmly_id from mi_exclude_families WHERE context_cd = 'REVERT') " +
                                    "AND EXISTS " + "(SELECT 1 FROM mi_entities_bl AS enty_bl WHERE fmly.fmly_id = enty_bl.fmly_id)";    

var conn = new OracleConnection("<connection string>");
var cmd = new OracleCommand(stmt, conn);
IDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

conn.Open();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Remove the semi-colon at the end of the SELECT statement and it should work.